create snowflake table from spark dataframe
I have my data in s3 location being read into a spark dataframe which I need to push into snowflake. Can snowflake create the table at runtime if the table doesn't exists by the following code?
self.df_source.
write \
.format(SNOWFLAKE_SPARK_CONNECTOR_DRIVER) \
.option("dbtable", f"{self.snowflake_database}.{self.snowflake_schema}. {self.snowflake_table}") \
.options(**self.render_connection_metadata()) \
.option("column_mapping", "name") \
.mode(self.mode) \
.save()

If not how can we create the snowflake table before ingesting the data as we don't know the datatype of each column.

So when you ran the code, did it create the table?

yes it creates the table with this command

The table gets created if it does not exist
